# Why is GitVersion Semver patch number offsetting automatically?

Tags: git, semantic-versioning, gitversion

Maybe a really silly question, but I'm new to GitVersion and trying to set it up in our repo for the first time. I created a branch off of the master branch `feature/playing-with-gitversion`, installed GitVersion via chocolatey and ran through the setup `gitversion init`. Gitflow and Mainline modes are what I configured the repo for. I would like to set the next-version variable to 1.0.30 (we had been doing semver manually and already used 1-29), but it keeps offsetting the patch number +60

Here is my GitVersion.yml file:

```
assembly-versioning-scheme: MajorMinorPatch
mode: Mainline
next-version: 1.0.30
branches:
  feature: {}
ignore:
  sha: []
merge-message-formats: {}
```

And here is what the semver ends up being:

```
gitversion /showvariable MajorMinorPatch                                                                                                                                                
1.0.90
```

I would really like gitversion to just honor the 1.0.30 from GitVersion.yml. I have tried [clearing the cache](https://github.com/GitTools/GitVersion/issues/937) and also trying gitversion /overrideconfig pre-release-weight=0 thinking that variable might be the culprit. What (hopefully) simple thing am I overlooking?

Comment: Doesn't GitVersion use repo tags to track the last high water mark for the branch?  Have you got a stray tag perhaps?

Comment: There are a few tags with version numbers, but I also added those same ones to a dummy repo and setup gitversion there, yet no luck reproducing the +60. In the original repo there are over 100 commits, which I thought might be a contributing factor, so exactly +60 seems suspicious to me.

Comment: I would take this up with the [GitVersion](https://github.com/GitTools/GitVersion) folks.